# Apache Kafka Cluster - Consumer Does Not Work (no brokers found when trying to rebalance)

Tags: apache-kafka

**Background:**
I am on apache kafka 0.10.1.0. I am running a kafka cluster with 3 nodes. I have topic with a replication-factor of 3, and 1 partition. With the intention of testing fault tolerance, I restarted node3. Manually started zk and kafka server on this node. When I describe the replicated topic, I get this:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 192.168.33.21:2181 --topic replicated-topic-1
    Topic:replicated-topic-1        PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3    Configs:
            Topic: replicated-topic-1       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 1,2,3
```

This tells me that the cluster survived a failure. I produced 10 messages to test the cluster.

**Problem:**
Now, when I try to use a console consumer, it works with node1 & node2 but when I use node3 (the one that restarted), it gives me a warning `no brokers found when trying to rebalance` and doesn't consumer any messages (there are 10 in my case):

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 192.168.33.23:2181 --topic replicated-topic-1 --from-beginning
[2016-10-29 01:35:43,276] WARN [console-consumer-55914_debian-70rc1-x64-vbox4210-1477704943013-947af681], no brokers found when trying to rebalance. (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
^CProcessed a total of 0 messages
```

If I use either of the other two nodes (1 or 2), I do get all 10 messages that I have in the topic. What is interesting to note is that I used node3 to describe the topic, and it still works fine. Just that the consumer is not able to use node3 to consume no matter how many times I reload & restart it. How do I fix node3 without restarting my cluster?